# MessageBox, Windows Form и кнопка ОК

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Я хочу сделать в Windows Forms приложение, в котором при нажатии кнопки появлялось бы простое сообщение "Не сюда", но проблема заключается в том, что во всплывающем окне появляется кнопка ОК, которую я не прописывал. Можете подсказать, как её можно убрать?

Comment: Убрать кнопки вы не можете, можете лишь переопределить на [заготовленные](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons). Хотите без кнопок, делайте форму, стилизуйте ее под нужный вам вид, и вызывайте `.Show()` у ее экземпляра.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать форму, которая будет выглядеть как всплывающее сообщение, к примеру:

```
Forma message = new Forma();
Message.Show();
```

И на этой форме разместите текст с помощью `label`, и запретите кнопки свёртывания и развёртывания

```
this.MaximizeBox = false; 
this.Resize = false;
```

На счёт `resize` точно сказать не могу, но решение выглядит просто

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, вы ищете всплывающее сообщение, которое показывает уведомление, а затем исчезает само по себе через короткое время.

Пример этого показан [здесь](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.2e56d4f5-64880e71-79f66c73-74722d776562/https/www.codeguru.com/csharp/form-fade-in-out-effect-and-notification-window/)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)